# Finding honorific text and then capital letters in Python

Tags: python, file, text, analysis, capitalization

```
file = open('AllCongress.txt', "r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
a = ""
b = ""
c = ""
d = ""
e = ""
f = ""
g = ""
y = ""
z = ""
for x in lines:
    if ((x == "M") or (a == "M")):
        a == "M"
        if((x == "r") or (b == "r")):
            b == "r"
            if((x == ".") or (c == ".")):
                c == "."
                if((x == " ") or (d == " ")):
                    d == " "
                    if((x == x.isupper()) or (e == "A"):
                        e == "A"
                        if((x == x.isupper()) and ((e == "A") and (f == "A"))):
                            f == "A"
                            
                            if((x == x.isupper()) or (g == g.isupper())):
                                g == "A"
```

I'm trying to divide sections of a .txt file into two separate files based on whether it contains a male or female speaker. Speakers in this file type have their last name in all caps after the honorific. So the male honorific format for speakers in this file is "Mr. XYZ" with XYZ being any 3+ capital letters (3 capital letters in a row is enough to detect anybody in the file as a speaker). The female format is similar, just either "Ms. XYZ" or "Mrs. XYZ".

I want to get all of the text after a speaker name like that is listed and then sort them into separate male and female text file, until the next speaker speaks where I have to determine gender again to sort.

Unfortunately though, I'm new to Python and I'm unable to figure out a way that I can check for both "Mr. " or "Mrs. " and then at least 3 capital letters in a row afterwards. I really just need a way to detect this and I can probably figure out the rest. The code above is this really messy and unfinished way I tried to capture the "Mr. XYZ" part of text.

Comment: what have you tried? please show some more code. Also can you show part of that `.txt` file?

Answer (score 1):

here is some code (if you have questions -> ask):

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as file:
    lines = file.read()

lines = lines.split(' ')
for index, word in enumerate(lines):
    if word == 'Mr.' and lines[index + 1].isupper():
        prefix = 'Mr. '
        name = lines[index + 1]
        print(prefix + name)
    elif word == 'Mrs.' and lines[index + 1].isupper():
        prefix = 'Mrs. '
        name = lines[index + 1]
        print(prefix + name)
```

I suggest you use `with` statement for opening files. Basically you loop over each word and check if it eaquals what you need.

Comment: One problem with this is that sometimes the text will have people's names in it with the prefix Mr. , but with a last name that isn't all caps (this means they're just being referred to by the speaker). The speaker has their last name after the prefix in all caps, and I want to make sure I divide it only by the speaker, not by random Mr. or Mrs.' they mention in the text. (Sorry my example text didn't capture this but it'd look something like "Mr. ROBERTS. Madam speaker, Mr. Stark has just said something blah blah blah"

Answer (score 0):

Use String functions like startswith() or endswith()
And don't close the file before reading lines

```
file = open('AllCongress.txt', "r")
lines = file.readlines()
lines = lines.split(' ')
for x in lines:
 if(x.startswith("Mr."):
  *code here*
 elif(x.startswith("Ms."):
  *code here*
```

Comment: The one problem with this is that sometimes they have names of people in the text like Mr. Roberts or something like this, but if the last name is all caps, it is the speaker whose name I actually want to grab the text after. I'm mostly having trouble determining how to tell if they have both "Mr." and then at least 3 capital letters in a row afterwards (which denotes they're the speaker and not just some random name in the text)